# Delete only referenced Nodes

Tags: views

[image]

I have created a report of each students with their paid fee invoices.

Now I would like to delete the invoices only.

Please help me out from this.

Comment: Do you want to delete all invoices? Invoices of a particular student?

Comment: Yes Mr. AjitS.. only Invoices... Not the Student..
Students data I need for the next academic year....

Comment: Just for the sake of clarification : I assume Student is a content type, so is Invoice. Right? And how are you referring invoice from student? Using a node reference or an entity reference?

Comment: Through Node references only

Comment: Now the actual problem is when I delete the invoices using VBO it delete the student also... :(

Comment: Answered. Let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be solved by creating a simple view with VBO. Try this steps:

1. Create a view of content, without any filter criteria.
2. Add a relationship to the view of the reference field in the 'student' content type. Say 'field_invoice'.
3. Add a filter to the view of "content type", select 'invoice'. **Use** the relationship in the filter that was created in step 2.
4. Add a filter of "content title". Expose this filter. **Use** the relationship in this filter too.
5. Add a VBO field of type  "Bulk operations: Content (Content)". Select 'delete' from the operations.

From this view, you should be able to filter by name of any student. It will list the invoices. And using VBO, you should be able to delete them.

Comment: ohhh My God.. at last I got the solutions thank you AjitS